# Limits of memory use on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I want to know the feasibility of these things:

1) Is it possible to download 200MB audio files to our application?

2) How much RAM can be accessed from an iPhone app? What is the largest amount of RAM an app can expect to use?

Anyone's help in this regard is deeply appreciated.

Thanks to all,
Monish

Comment: You need to be clearer on what you mean by memory. The iPhone does not have 8 gigabytes of RAM, but of flash. It should be no problem downloading  200 megabytes to the flash.

Comment: I mean about iphone ram support.How much can we input??

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question. Also, it could be better if you stated what problem you are trying to solve. Maybe we can find a way to not use as much RAM.  If you really, really need that amount of RAM, you are not going to solve the problem on an iPhone.

Comment: @clark:Its Ok I dnt mine that u had taken the liberty to edit my question.Ok thanks for ur prompt answer.

Comment: I need to download more than 700 audio files from the server and save them locally. Every audio file will take minimum 40 seconds for downloading. So it will take at least 7 hours to download all the files. Is this scenario works ?. As I need to store them locally it will be 500 mb or more. Is iPhone's memory management works with this figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes, although you might make users angry who are not on Wifi + fast DSL. Also you will need to handle interrupted downloads.

2) No, since ARM is a 32bit processor a maximum of 4GB RAM can be addressed. Anyhow, iDevices have a maximum of 512MB right now (iPad 2). Your application will get killed by iOS if your app takes about 75% or so of the available RAM which means in reality you shouldn't use more than, say, 80MB of RAM. And if you *need* to address 8GB then your design is totally flawed to begin with.

There are always ways to work with a lot less (e. g. either by using better algorithms and/or by caching to disk). On the disk, you are only limited by the available space left on the device. So if you have an iDevice with just 8GB you're naturally out of luck as the system itself and other apps/data are reducing the available space. Same if you're on a 64GB iDevice which is packed with movies. You will need to be able to work with the space that is available. You can, for example, try to "reserve" the necessary space by creating a file and making it as big as you need it (via a seek and a write) but be prepared for angry customers.

Comment: I need to download more than 700 audio files from the server and save them locally. Every audio file will take minimum 40 seconds for downloading. So it will take at least 7 hours to download all the files. Is this scenario works ?. As I need to store them locally it will be 500 mb or more. Is iPhone's memory management works with this figure?

Comment: Well, it's no problem to download and store hundreds of files. The iPhone is just another computer, after all, with a normal file system. But I guess you really need to think about the design of your app. An app that downloads this amount will not be a good experience. First, the long time for the download. Then, some people will have to pay for that bandwidth. Next, people will notice their iDevice is suddenly full. Sounds like a guaranteed bad rating in App Store ;-) Can you, for example, reduce the quality of the sound files to make them smaller ? And/or reduce the amount of files ?

Comment: Asked another way: what kind of app do you want to write ? What does it do ?

Comment: the customers may not be angry at all if this is what they expect. This may not necessarily be an ordinary app for the app store. It may be something custom for a customer who knows what to expect. A DJ, or whatever. Or it may be some kind of retail store music player or something using an iDevice as the jukebox. Who knows what this is? :)

Comment: I also have similar requirement. However i dont want to store so many files. I think we will restrict to 4-5 audio files. But for good performance and occupy low storage what should be the limit for each audio file? We don't want that the users upload large files on the server and want to put restriction on the size of audio file